# CAShapeLayer isn't visible

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, cocoa-touch

I have a subclass of `UIView` connected to a `XIB` file of a `UIViewController`.

I'm using `PocketSVG` to convert my `SVG` file to `CGPath` like that:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        let myPath = PocketSVG.pathFromSVGFileNamed("").takeUnretainedValue()

        let myShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        myShapeLayer.path = myPath

        myShapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor
        myShapeLayer.lineWidth = 3
        myShapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

        self.layer.addSublayer(myShapeLayer)
    }
```

the problem is that when I run the app I can't see anything, the layer isn't visible.

What am I doing wrong now?

Thank you!

Comment: If you breakpoint and print `myShapeLayer`, what is its frame? At first glance, it seems like you haven't given the shape layer a frame, which means its frame is `CGRectZero` and it won't show up on the screen.

Comment: First, are you sure you're getting a valid `CGPathRef`? I'd check `myPath`. Second, when you override `awakeFromNib`, you might want to call `super`.

Comment: @keithbhunter Yes, the frame is `0,0,0,0`, to change it to `self.view`?

Comment: @Rob How can I check `myPath`? `PocketSVG` returns a `CGPath`

Comment: Re `frame` of shape layer, set it to `self.view.bounds`. Re `myPath`, make sure it's not null. Second, you can call various CGPath functions, like `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox`, and see if you get a reasonable rect from that.

Comment: @Rob I get `(0.0, 1118.05603027344, 750.0, 215.943969726562)` from `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(myPath)`

Comment: Hmm. The `y` value is 1118; unless your view is taller than 1118 points, I'm not sure you'd see the path...

Comment: @Rob Why is it so big?

Comment: @Rob How can I change the `y` position of a `CGPath`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given what you reported for `CGPathGetPathBoundingBox`, you may want to transform the path so it falls within the visible portion of the window.

For example, if you want to translate and scale this so it fits the view:

```
let insetRect = CGRectInset(bounds, lineWidth / 2.0, lineWidth / 2.0)
let boundingRect = CGPathGetPathBoundingBox(myPath)
let scale = min(insetRect.size.height / boundingRect.size.height, insetRect.size.width / boundingRect.size.width)
var transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-boundingRect.origin.x * scale + insetRect.origin.x, -boundingRect.origin.y * scale + insetRect.origin.y), scale, scale)

let transformedPath = CGPathCreateMutableCopyByTransformingPath(myPath, &transform)
```

There are lots of permutations on this idea, but hopefully it illustrates the concept.

Comment: Thank you! That's works!! but the size is smaller then it should be, I want it to be in the size of the view. How can I do that?

Comment: I set it up to use the minimum scale needed to fit the whole thing in the view. Your path was awfully wide, yet not very tall, so it would appear scrunched up at the top of the view. You can adjust this `scale` as you see fit. You can also adjust the `transform`, too (e.g. to center it or what have you). Or maybe you let the user adjust the `scale` with a pinch-zoom.

Comment: can you please show me how can I set it to the maximum size of the view?

Comment: If you use `max` instead of `min`, it will probably make it fill the view (but it will cut some off, too).

Comment: can you please share an updated code example to make me understand that better?

Comment: In that line that says `let scale = ...`, replace `min` with `max`. Or replace that whole line with `let scale: CGFloat = 1.0`.

Comment: that's cuts half of the shape, I want the width to be equals to the view, the height doesn't really matter to me

Comment: If you don't care about height, you can just do `let scale = insetRect.size.width / boundingRect.size.width`. By the way, make sure your view to which you're adding this is the width you think it is (e.g. `print(bounds)`).

Comment: what's `insetRect`?

Comment: See the revised code sample in my question, in which I adjusted the transform to make sure it accounted for you lineWidth of the shape layer. Without that inset process, it would crop off the shape layer's border line.

Comment: what do you mean by `lineWidth`? The `myShapeLayer.lineWidth`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: I can't tell you why it doesn't work if you don't tell us precisely what happened. Edit your original question, including (a) example SVG file; (b) what it generated; and (c) if there are errors, share the complete and precise error message text and/or, in the case of crashes, the stack trace

Comment: I moved this to `layoutSubviews` and it worked. Thank you! now the last question ;) how can I snap the path to the bottom of the view instead of to the top? Thanks again!

Comment: Just change the translation factor. So figure out what the new scaled height is, and then adjust the y value if the translation accordingly.